# Streaming in OpenCL

Tags: memory, stream, opencl

I'm going to write an OpenCL program which processes a huge amount of data on task level (no further parallelism is possible, but data amount is high enough)
The data itself is read from a file and the results should be written to another file.
Now I thought it might be the best (fastest) to let 1 thread read the file and push the data to the kernels while another threads gets the finished data and writes it to a file.
So I would actually need something like ReadData->CopyToDevice->ExecuteKernel->CopyToHost->WriteData

Is there any example, how to do this best? I'd start with an array of like 10 (queues, InputMemory, OutputMemory, Events).
First Thread: Read Data, wait for next event entry to be null, fill in this array, next
2nd Thread: event!=null->waitforevent, write Data, set event to null
Or maybe use a 10-Semaphore instead of checking for null

Answer (score 1):

Also, use separate OpenCL command queues for upload, process, and download, with clEvents to create dependencies between them. This will allow the hardware to overlap these operations when the GPU support

Answer (score 0):

I am doing something [similar](http://ufo.kit.edu/repos/ufo-core) for image processing but before thinking about doing anything you should actually profile to see where the bottlenecks are. I don't know how compute-intensive your kernels are but you should not underestimate I/O.

First of all: yes, using three threads in total is probably a good idea to hide I/O latencies. But ten command queues is way too much, one for each GPU is more than enough. Moreover, if you have only one GPU it is pointless to feed it ten different buffers, if it's only capable of processing one. So you are better off with a double-buffer strategy and blocking reads and writes.

Comment: The kernel itself processes data of fixed size and variable sized output. One CPU can do about 10k of datasets per second (~150B each)  
So I thought about giving the kernel about 10k datasets split on 31 WorkItems per Group (31 due to local memory requirements) and a few groups.

Comment: So I thought while I'm transferring data to the kernel, I can do the calculation in the kernel for previous datasets and read the data from disk for the next datasets. So it would be like a pipeline with 4 stages: Read from disk, write to device, process data/read from device, write to disk.  
There is an example doing calculations in one queue while the other queue is transferring data and than the other way round. So the same kernel is instantiated 2 times and so called on 2 queues. The kernels could even run at the same time, given enough CU can't they?

Comment: There is no guarantee how transfers and executions are scheduled in non-blocking mode except for order. So you could use the same queue for transfer and execution. A queue is merely an abstraction of sending the GPU information (either kernel execution or data). But why not just trying?

Comment: An In-Order-Queue is AFAIK a normal FIFO Queue. So if I enqueue the transfer and the kernel in one queue it is executed in that order. So Kernel execution starts after transferring the data. Good enough for a single kernel call. But if I enqueue the same again, than the 2nd transfer WILL start after first kernel finishes.
If I enqueue it into another queue instead the transfer MIGHT start before the first kernel finishes which gives me the advantage of hiding the copy delay. Or do I miss anything?

Comment: Ah, now I see your point. You are right, you could use two independent queues for transferring and submitting kernel execution. And of course you then need to pass the read/write events to the preceeding/succeeding kernel execution.